# Conditional probability and chain rule: math problem

Tags: probability, proof-verification

> A driver who causes a collision must undergo a blood test. Experience shows that if someone is under the influence of alcohol, there is a 75% chance that the result will be positive. For someone who is not under the influence, however, there is also a 5% chance that the result will be positive.

So, summarizing: $p(T+|I+)=0,75$ and $p(T+|I-)=0,05$.

Part 1 of this problem was the find the chance $p(I+|T+)$, knowing that $p(I+)=0,01$. I've already found the answer: $p(I+|T+)=0,132$ (which corresponds to the answers in my booklet).

Part 2 is where it gets trickier:

> If the result is positive, a second test will take place. For people who are not under the influence and with a positive result on the first test, it is always negative; for people under the influence and with a positive result on the first test, there is a 95% chance of a positive result on the second test. What is the conditional probability that someone will be under the influence if the second test is negative and the first test was positive?

We know that $p(T_2 -|T_1 +, I-) = 1$ and $p(T_2+|T_1+,I+)=0,95$. We need to find $p(I+|T_1+,T_2-)$.

I applied the chain rule for $p(I+,T_1+,T_2-)$ in two different ways:

$$ p(I+,T_1+,T_2-) = p(I+)p(T_1+|I+)p(T_2-|T_1+,I+) = 0,01\cdot 0,75\cdot0,05=0,000375.$$ And $$ p(I+,T_1+,T_2-)=p(T_1+)p(T_2-|T_1+)p(I+|T_1+,T_2-) = 0,000375,$$

with $p(T_1+) = 0,75\cdot 0,01 + 0,05 \cdot 0,99 = 0,057$ and $p(T_2-|T_1+) = 0,05\cdot 0,01 + 1\cdot 0,99 = 0,9905$.

Solving for our unknown: $p(I+|T_1+,T_2-) = \frac{0,000375}{0,057\cdot 0,9905} = 0,00664$.

This, however, is not what my book says the answer should be ($0,00752$). I rechecked thrice, but maybe I'm still overlooking some important details?

Can anyone help me pinpoint my mistake? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have (A-alcohol,S-sober):
$$P(A|+,-)=\frac{P(A,+,-)}{P(A,+,-)+P(S,+,-)}=\\
=\frac{0.01\cdot 0.75\cdot 0.05}{0.01\cdot 0.75\cdot 0.05+0.99\cdot 0.05\cdot 1}=\\
\frac{0.000375}{0.049875}=0.00751879699...$$